# Hibernate doesn't persist when inserting long texts

Tags: java, mysql, spring, postgresql, hibernate

I'm using Postgresql 9.6 and before I was using mySQL an I get the same problem with the two databases. I also have the same problem with Hibernate 4 and 5.

When I'm trying to persist an Object with a long String inside, it never ends the method session.persist(object). In the other hand it works perfectly when the string ismySQL an I get the same problem with the two databases.
 not that long, like this paragraph.

addVehicle method in VehicleDAO.java

```
public Vehicle addVehicle(Vehicle vehicle) {
    Session session = 
    this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
    session.persist(vehicle);
    return vehicle;
}
```

Vehicle attributes:

```
public class Vehicle {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "idvehicle")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    int idVehicle;

    @Column(name = "name")
    String name;

    @Column(name = "description")
    String description;

    @Column(name = "photob64")
    String photoB64;
```

Eclipse console log:

```
Hibernate: insert into vehicle (description, name, photob64, idvehicletype) values (?, ?, ?, ?)
```

Comment: Two things to check: 1. Column in DB might has constraints which limit max character amount 2. Check if transaction is committed at the end

Comment: @KamilW. in Postgresql the limit of a column of type text is 1GB

Comment: Can you execute this SQL directly on DB. It will allows us to track on which side (hibernate / database) a issue can be.

Comment: The problem is on DB side. The query hangs if I execute it through console

Comment: How long is this string? Maybe it needs more time to be inserted. Execute query and leave if for minutes, see what's happen after that, i think postgres must return some error code.

Comment: It's around 5k characters. I'll let you know if I get any message

Comment: SSL SYSCALL error: Connection timed out

Comment: Try to insert the record directly in the DB using an SQL Client to see if the problem is indeed on the DB side or the application.

Comment: Saving the photo to the database will really blow-up the size of your database backups. I know from experience, so I advise you not to do it. But if you will do it anyway, It was done using a `bytea` db column in postgres and `byte[]` field in Java using Hibernate 4.3 and it worked for us, until it started impacting performance. Converting it to base64 and saving as text will only impact you worse when it comes to performance.

Comment: @coladict I've been trying with byte[ ] as bytea and the problem persists

Answer (score 0):

**Hibernate doesn't persist when inserting long texts**

As per your question, it doesn't persist when inserting long texts. It's is because by default String lenght is 255. You can see in database. The VARCHAR(255) lenght is 255. 
You can mentioned length by using below approach:

```
@Column(name=" description", length = 300)
private String description;
```

If you are not sure of length, then it's good idea to go with lob, blob or clob as per your need. You can read details of lob, blob and clob and select one of them. For text lob or clob will work for you.

Comment: As I said, the type TEXT in Postgresql has 1GB of capacity

Comment: I'm not sure why you are using getCurrentSession() instead of openSession() in your application. If it's web application it's better to use openSession. Try this approach as well. If my answer doesn't solve your problem. Remember, In case of openSession you need to close session. There is different between openSession and getCurrentSession. You can go through that as well and understand it better.

Comment: It does nothing using openSession() instead

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways,

1. You can set columnDefinition like

   ```
   @Column(name = "notes", columnDefinition = "varchar(300)")
   private String notes;
   ```
2. If you don't know maximum length of string you can set columnDefinition as text like

   ```
   @Column(name = "notes", columnDefinition = "text")
   private String notes;
   ```

Answer (score 0):

I figured out what was happening. The method persist never ended because the information couldn't be transferred completely to the DB which was in other device, a Raspberry Pi.

I changed the MTU of the network adapters of my PC and Raspberry Pi to 1492 with the command:

```
sudo ifconfig eth0 mtu 1492
```

More info: http://www.ubuntugeek.com/how-to-change-mtu-maximum-transmission-unit-of-network-interface-in-ubuntu-linux.html